# Groupby on two columns with bins(ranges) on one of them in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I am trying to make segregate my data into buckets based on certain user attributes and I would like to see some counts in each of the buckets.For this I have imported this data into a Pandas Dataframe.

I have data that has user city, kids age and their unique id. I would like to know the count of users who reside in city A and have kids in age group 0-5.

Sample Data frame looks something like this:

```
city  kids_age  user_id
A         10       1  
B          4       2
A          4       3        
C          8       4
A          3       5
```

Expected Output:

```
city   bin   count
A      0-5      2 
       5-10     1

B      0-5      1
       5-10     0

C      0-5      0
       5-10     1
```

I tried group by on two columns city and kids age:

```
user_details_df_cropped_1.groupby(['city', 'kids_age']).count()
```

It gave me an output that looks something like this:

```
city  kids_age  user_id   count
 A      10       1          1
         4       3          1
         3       5          1
 B       4       2          1 
 C       8       4          1
```

I returns me the users grouped by city, but not really by kids age bins(ranges). What am I missing here? Appreciate the help!!

Comment: What happens if the age is 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for binning, pass to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), add `0` rows with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
[`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) an last convert to `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
bins = [0,5,10]
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
b = pd.cut(df['kids_age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

df = df.groupby(['city', b]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  city kids_age  count
0    A      0-5      2
1    A     5-10      1
2    B      0-5      1
3    B     5-10      0
4    C      0-5      0
5    C     5-10      1
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for added mising rows filled by `0`:

```
bins = [0,5,10]
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
b = pd.cut(df['kids_age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['city'].unique(), labels], names=['city','kids_age'])

df = (df.groupby(['city', b])
        .size()
        .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)
  city kids_age  count
0    A      0-5      2
1    A     5-10      1
2    B      0-5      1
3    B     5-10      0
4    C      0-5      0
5    C     5-10      1
```

Comment: solution 1 definitely worked for me, have not tried solution 2 though. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What happens if the age is 0?

Comment: then use `include_lowest=True` parameter ;)

Comment: perfect! @jezrael